# How to correctly add a node to a linked list from the right

Tags: c, list

I want to write a function that, passed by two parameters (the name of a file and a global list), does the following: if the list is empty and the file exists, the function starts reading the content of the file. For each character, it generates a node in the linked list where is stored the character, and then adds the node to the list from the right. Finally, the function returns, as parameters, the list created and the value 1, otherwise, it ends the execution of the function, and returns 0 as a parameter.

The following is the solution provided by my textbook of the exercise, but I can't understand how it returns the list "l". In this case, "l" shouldn't be pointing to the first node only?

```
struct el {
struct el *next;
char data;
};
struct el *list=NULL;

int add (char *name, struct el **l) {
   FILE *f; char c;
   struct el *temp, *last = NULL; 
   f= fopen(name, "r");
   if (f==NULL || (*l)!=NULL){
   printf("errf");
   return 0;
   }
   c=fgetc(f);
   while (c!=EOF) {
      temp= (struct el *) malloc(sizeof(struct el));
      if (temp==NULL) return 0;
      temp->data=c;
      temp->next=NULL;
      if (*l==NULL){
        last=temp;
        *l=temp;
      }
      else{
        last->next=temp;
        last=temp;
    }
   c=fgetc(f);
   }
  fclose(f);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should put parens around your if statement, this formatting could use some love.

Comment: First of all, [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an `int`. This is actually very important for the `EOF` check.

Comment: As for understanding the code, do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*, and [learn how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `struct el **l` is a pointer on a pointer variable. So, you should use it like this `struct el *l;  add("file", &el);` Then `el` will  contain root of the linked list, if function returns 1, otherwise function fails and l is undefined (so you don't need to free list nodes by calling free)

Comment: *"In this case, "l" shouldn't be pointing to the first node only?"* - no, it points the the *pointer* that is pointing to the first node. And given that, you don't actually need `temp` or `last` in this code if you configure and manage `l` throughout the function properly. Removing those actually makes the function *easier* to implement and understand, so think about it. This looks like a straight-up forward-chained linked list.

Comment: Draw the pointers on a piece of paper, it will help immensely.

Comment: @rustyx I did, and I figured out that the pointers "temp" and "last" were pointing dynamically, whereas "l" was _pointing the pointer that is pointing to the first node_.

Comment: Maybe I am just wrong, but I couldn't understand what is the correct way to pass the list "l".

Comment: @Kevin If you mean how do you pass the global `list` to this function, the caller would do something like `int res = add(fname, &list);` within whatever function you're calling this from, assuming `fname` is whatever filename you're using. Btw, you also have a potential file leak in this function. `if (temp==NULL) return 0;` leaves `f` opened and orphaned into the ether. That's not good.

Comment: Regarding what I said before (removing `temp` and `last`), as well as fixing the orphaned file pointer, consider [something like this](https://pastebin.com/NWEeb9Nn). It frankly still has a hole in that it can return a partial list on an error condition, but it is hopefully easier to understand, and worthy of stepping though in a debugger.

Comment: "I can't understand how it returns the list `"l"`": The code does not return `l`.  It returns an `int`.  The function `add (char *name, struct el **l)` receives a pointer to `struct el *`.  The code can then change the pointer `l` points to.

Comment: @chux Yes, maybe instead of int, it could just be a void. The function is supposed to receive an empty linked list and then add nodes.

Comment: Kevin, certainly `add()` should **not** receive "an empty linked list" (`struct el *`), but receive a pointer  to  "an empty linked list" (`struct el **`).

Comment: @chux, @WhozCraig I think I figured out the error. Maybe adding `*l=last;` under `last=temp;` `else{
        last->next=temp;
        last=temp;
    }` solves the problem?

Comment: @Kevin Post the code that calls `add()` to understand how it returns the list `"l"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `add` takes two parameters: the name of a file and a pointer to a pointer of `struct el` (list of lists).  It's worth noting that the function ***only*** operates on the first "list" or `*l` or `l[0]`

```c
if (*l==NULL){     // if no characters in the first list of l then
  last=temp;       //   initialize the list with the first character
  *l=temp;
}
else{              // else the first list of l has been initialized so
  last->next=temp; //   add new reference and data to current end node
  last=temp;
}
```

Since you initialize the first list `*l` with the same pointer as `last`, you're still creating the link when assigning your current `struct el` pointer to `last->next` while maintaining `*l`'s pointer to the root node.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!